# How to post a blog without public access

Tags: privacy, blogging

I want to keep a blog with pictures and videos of my kid growing up but I don't want it to be open to the public. I just want me and my wife to be able to post to it and then share with grandparents and friends.

I'm at the start so I would like a platform (blogger, wordpress, ...) that has these features and that also allows export of the data (if one day I want to migrate to a different platform).

I've been trying out blogger which allows you to have a private blog. But when I upload images they get stored in a hard to guess URL but are otherwise public. Are there better options to this?

For videos I think I am happy with embedding Vimeo videos since they ask for a password to be viewed but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Why is this closed? In the day and age that all the talk is about cloud-computing, how is a question asking how to privately publish material on the cloud not a software question?

Comment: Please review the FAQ. Super User does not allow questions on Websites and Webservices.

Comment: Where's the FAQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I self-host a family blog and I've tried a few different setups for this. The easiest I've found is Wordpress with a plugin to require authentication. I currently use "Authenticator" for that.

I prefer this to an .htaccess file because for those who I let post, it's only one username and password for them to remember. And they can reset that password when they forget it without any intervention on my part.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to recommend Blogger and I think that the picture links are quite hard to guess.

If however you have any webspace or an always on 24x7 machine, you can always host [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org) yourself and limit who can access via `.htaccess` files or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an account at [wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com) and then password-protect all your content. (The blog itself will be visible, but no one will be able to see the content without knowing the password.) You can host text, images, and video.

I don't know how wordpress.com manages images, though.

Comment: AFAIK, there's a way on Wordpress.com for users not to attach URIs to images, so even if they do see the images, they won't see any URI listed even when they hover their cursor over them.